# Insert/Remove device - A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: c#, com, serial-port, at-command

I have this sample to send AT command to GSM modem using the Serial Port. The method to send AT command is ExecuteATCommand().

```
        ExecuteATCommand(this.SerialPort, "AT", 300, "No phone connected");
        ExecuteATCommand(this.SerialPort, "AT+CSMP=49,167,0,0", 300, "No phone connected");
        ExecuteATCommand(this.SerialPort, "AT+CNMI=2,2,0,1,0", 300, "No phone connected");
        ExecuteATCommand(this.SerialPort, "AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.")
```

I have a situation when the GSM modem is already connected to PC (through USB port). If  I remove and insert it again, the ExecuteATCommand() method throws the exception **A device attached to the system is not functioning**.

Comment: Are you giving it enough time before you call the function?  What does it look like in Windows Device Manager, is the COM port present without yellow triangles?

Comment: It's about 10 seconds.

Comment: I would make sure that the device is really ready to communicate.  They can be quite slow sometimes.